# Identifying first page a customer visited on the most recent day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem that I can't quite figure out while practicing my SQL skills, and hoping to get some enlightenment here.

Based on a table schema with a data row as example shown below:

```
click_datetime    |    click_day    |     customer_id    |     page_id
6/5/2016 0:31          6/5/2016           1111               ABCDE
```

I would like to obtain the first page_id that each customer visited on the most recent day.

The tricky part is that I would need to find the MAX of each customer's click_day, before finding the minimum value of each customer's click_datetime to then select the page_id.

So far this is what I've got:

```
SELECT customer_id, MAX(click_day), page_id
FROM 
(SELECT customer_id, click_day, page_id, MIN(click_datetime) FROM Clickdata 
GROUP BY customer_id, click_day, page_id) Clickdata
WHERE page_id != ''
GROUP BY customer_id, page_id
```

You can find the SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8cabb/29

So far I can't quite seem to get the final output which should only show me one page_id value for each customer, with its corresponding last day visit. But somehow I'm still getting multiple rows.

Could anyone kindly point me to what I'm doing wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: You should be storing dates as a DATE / DATETIME datatype...

Comment: Thanks @RaymondNijland, i just used the text to DDL function and didn't realized they just store everything as a varchar!

Comment: *"i just used the text to DDL function and didn't realized they just store everything as a varchar!"* Fair enough just a heads up as MIN and MAX can get wrong results on strings when date comparing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
select
    *
from
    (   select
            *,
            row_number() over(  partition by
                                    customer_id
                                order by
                                    to_date(click_day, 'dd/mm/yyyy') desc,  -- use click_day without conversion if it is of type "date"
                                    click_datetime) as rn
        from
            Clickdata) as x
where
    rn = 1
```

Comment: I tried running this on the SQL fiddle and it doesn't seem to work though :(

Comment: sorry, fixed, `as x` added

Comment: Thank you! If I only need the output to have customer_id, click_day and page_id, do I just replace the * with those 3 variables ? Sorry, still trying to digest on the usage of partition by

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with NOT EXISTS and a CTE:

```
with cte as (
  select c.* from clickdata c
  where not exists (
    select 1 from clickdata
    where customer_id = c.customer_id and click_day > c.click_day 
  )
)
select c.* from cte c
where not exists (
  select 1 from cte 
  where customer_id = c.customer_id and click_datetime < c.click_datetime 
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=85917c3b4410c04ccca99cacfec2f8fb).
Results:

```
> click_datetime      | click_day  | customer_id | page_id   
> :------------------ | :--------- | ----------: | :---------
> 2017-04-12 03:23:00 | 2017-04-12 |        1111 | B00T8HT71Y
> 2017-06-22 17:40:00 | 2017-06-22 |        2222 | B000VZPW5W
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I promise to learn well with this example as well!